# 2 test for convergence problems: $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}5^k/(3^k+4^k)$and $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\tan\left(1/n\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For the first problem: $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{5^k}{3^k+4^k}$$

I tried to take the ratio test but was having trouble simplifying $$\frac{3^k + 4^k}{3^{k+1} + 4^{k+1}}$$

For the second problem: $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

I don't know how to approach it.

Thanks for the help as always

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first problem

$$\frac{\frac{5^{k+1}}{3^{k+1}+4^{k+1}}}{\frac{5^k}{3^k+4^k}}$$

$$=\frac{5^{k+1}(3^k+4^k)}{5^k(3^{k+1}+4^{k+1})}$$

$$=5\cdot\frac{\left(\frac34\right)^k+1}{3\cdot\left(\frac34\right)^k+4}$$

So, using [Ratio Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RatioTest.html):  $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5^{k+1}}{3^{k+1}+4^{k+1}}}{\frac{5^k}{3^k+4^k}}=\frac54$$

Comment: How did you get the (3/4)^k ?

Comment: @BillyThompson, divide the numerator & the denominator by $4^k$

Comment: Ok so I follow everything you did, but I don't know how you arrived at the final answer from the equation you gave directly above the final answer. Can you please clarify how that equates to 5/4?

Comment: @BillyThompson $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$ if $|x|<1$ right?

Comment: Ahh gotcha, thanks :)

Comment: @BillyThompson: see this also. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/327326/8581.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{+1}\tan(n^{-1})=1<\infty$$ so the corresponding series is divergent. That is similar to the following series: $$\sum_1^\infty\sin\left(\frac{1}n\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

For the 2nd one use the limit comparison test with $\dfrac 1 n$, to show it diverges. For the 1st one note that, $\dfrac{5^k}{3^k+4^k}>\frac 1 2(\dfrac{5}{4})^k$ which does not tend to $0$.

Comment: For the 2nd one how come you can compare to 1/n? it would be tan(1/n)/(1/n) right? and doesn't this go to 0 as the limit goes to infinity? I thought for LCT it has to reach a positive finite value.

Comment: It goes to 1. as $\dfrac{\tan x}{x}\to 1$ as $x\to0$

Comment: is there some sort of rule in trig that tells you that x*tan(1/x) = tan(x)/x ? Because when I do LCT i get it in the form x.tan(1/x) ?

Comment: As $n\to \infty$ $\frac 1 n \to 0$ make the substitution and find the limit.

Comment: tan(0)/(1/n) right?

Comment: Let$ x= \dfrac{1}{n} $ then, $\dfrac{tan (\frac 1 n)}{\frac 1 n}=\dfrac{tan x}{x}$ and x tends to 0 as n gets bigger.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks